# Adding a delay in a command in r

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, delay

I am using the following code to get coordinates of cities from googlemaps api. Problem is that google returns the following error:

```
OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
```

for more than 5 requests in a second (and total of 2500 a day). I need to add a delay of 210ms each time it gets geocodes for each row in the code below. How can I do it in r?

```
mydata$geocode <- geocode(as.character(mydata$value))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Perhaps something like:

irist <- head(iris, 10)

irist$test <- NA

 for(i in 1: dim(irist)[1]){
   irist$test[i] <- irist$Sepal.Length[i] + 1
   print(irist$test)
   Sys.sleep(0.210)
 }
 [1] 6.1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6 6.0  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6 6.0 6.4  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6 6.0 6.4 5.6  NA  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6 6.0 6.4 5.6 6.0  NA  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6 6.0 6.4 5.6 6.0 5.4  NA
 [1] 6.1 5.9 5.7 5.6 6.0 6.4 5.6 6.0 5.4 5.9
> 
> t2 <- Sys.time()
> 
> t2-t1
Time difference of 2.261692 secs
```

So for you it could be:

```
uniquecitynamesbackers$geocode <- NA

for(i in 1: dim(uniquecitynamesbackers)[1]){
uniquecitynamesbackers$geocode[i] <- geocode(as.character(uniquecitynamesbackers$value[i]))
Sys.sleep(0.210)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the Sys.sleep() function like in this example:

```
myf <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(0.210)
  return(x+1)}

t1 <- Sys.time()
myf(1)
[1] 2

t2 <- Sys.time()

> t2-t1
Time difference of 0.221406 secs
```

So in your scenario the code could be:

```
mygeofunction <- function(x){
Sys.sleep(0.210) 
geocode(as.character(x))}

uniquecitynamesbackers$geocode <- mygeofunction(uniquecitynamesbackers$value)
```

Comment: Tried, it is not working. It adds a delay at the beginning and then runs the gecode repaetedly without delays... got the same error. It needs to get the first row (i.e city name), capture the related geocodes, then delay and next row...

Comment: Apologies. My other suggestion would be to write a for loop, I add it as a separate answer, although I am not sure it will be most efficient.